# pass arguments to alias then disown

Tags: bash, alias

I am trying to create a simple alias:

```
alias draw="pinta &> /dev/null & disown"
```

The intent here is pretty obvious.  My problem is that whenever I pass an argument, I get

```
bash: disown: file.jpg: no such job
```

and pinta opens without the file loaded.  How do I pass my argument to pinta and then disown the task?

EDIT:

I've tried explicitly passing the arguments as follows:

```
alias draw="pinta $* &> /dev/null & disown"
```

but I get the same result

Comment: You cannot pass arguments to an alias: the alias is expanded to the replacement text, then the rest of the line is appended (arguments, redirections, etc). Your arguments would be therefore be passed as parameters to **disown**, not **pinta** - the internal _$*_ is ignored (expanded to the null string). Try `alias echo2="echo 1-$@-1 ; echo 2-$@-2"` to see how it works. You can either use a function, as proposed by cYrus, or you can create a script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a function instead:

```
function draw {
    pinta "$@" &> /dev/null & disown
}
```

**Bonus:** You should use `"$@"` instead of `$*`.

Assume that you have:

```
function foo {
    echo "1: $1"
    echo "2: $2"
    echo "3: $3"
}

function bar {
    echo '$*'; foo $*
    echo '$@'; foo $@
    echo '"$*"'; foo "$*"
    echo '"$@"'; foo "$@"
}
```

Then try:

```
bar "f o o" bar baz
```

Only with `"$@"` you get the proper behavior.